# Solve ODE $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x+2t-6}{2x+t}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Equation is given in title. I tried with substitution $2x+t=u$, but I don't know how to solve it then - we get an equation $3t+12=3u-u'u$, where $u'=\frac{du}{dt}.$ In first moment I thought that it is homogenous, but it is very easy that it isn't. Please give me a hint, I don't want a solution. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the equation homogenous so what you do is you shift the coordinates to the point of intersection of two lines whose equations are the denominator and the numerator being equal to zero. 
Solving the two equations:
$$x+2t-6=0,$$
$$2x+t=0$$
gives you the point (-2,4) as a point of intersection,
shifting the coordinates to this point using the transformation 
$$ x'=x+2$$
$$t'=t-4$$
yields:
$$\frac{dx'}{dt'}=\frac{x'+2t'}{2x'+t'}$$
Which you can easily solve.